# Rendering CSS transition when React element's text changes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Here is a snippet of my code base - https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-code-1wr5z

Currently, via changing classes and CSS transitions, text fades in when a new Paragraph component is loaded in and mounted.

However, I wish to also have this transition occur when the text prop within the Paragraph component changes.

Doing this within the lifecycle update or render just triggers **an infinite update loop**.

Not sure where to go from here as most discussions I can find are about tackling the functionality of getting the text to fade in on load, rather than on update.

Comment: please check solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251416/6544460... it's working.

Comment: I would use an animation instead of a transition, and change the elements key when text is changed `key={text}`, so it would be re-added to the DOM, thus animation will run again.

Comment: @Cristy Thanks a lot - this definitely seems like the way to go. I'm rather new to React so is there any way you can elaborate on how I would go about implementing this?

Comment: I don't exactly what is the desired outcome. What if the text changes while the animation is playing? Should the animation restart (as the text changed) or continue (as it currently does with transitions) ?

Comment: We can assume the text won't change until the animation finishes playing (otherwise, we just restart the animation). I'm essentially going to have another component (think of it like a button) that changes the string being passed into the text prop when clicked on. Instead of the text just suddenly changing to the new string, I want the fade transition to smooth out the shift.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the snippet solution**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Style.css";

class Paragraph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   setInterval(() => {
     this.fade();
   }, 1000); 
  }

  fade() {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  }

  render() {
    const text = this.props.text;

    const classes = this.state.open ? "greenCls" : "redCls";

    return <div className={classes}>{text}</div>;
  }
}

export default Paragraph;
```

*css class*

```
.redCls {
  background: red;
}
.greenCls {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: So this works technically, but now the text is continually fading in and out every second due to the setInterval. Is there any way to restrict the animation to only occur once, when the "text" prop changes?

Edit: Actually, I don't believe this works. It's changing the class continually, but I need it specifically occur when the text changes, and only then.

Comment: @GeorgeLiebert you can change state value in shouldComponentUpdate when props changes and with the help of changed state you can animate.

Comment: Right, I think I've attempted this already. If I change the state value in shouldComponentUpdate the component updates again forcing "Maximum update depth exceeded."

Answer (score 0):

Please try using setTimeout to fix this issue

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-code-fgmyq
```